# Holder condition for $x^\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f(x)=x^\beta$ (for some fixed $0<\beta<1$) be defined on $(0,1)$. It's not hard to see that $f$ is $\beta$-Holder.

> How can I prove that $x^\beta$ is not $\alpha$-Holder for $\beta<\alpha<1$?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's enough to use a counter example, say $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 0.5$ then we have that

$$ |0^\beta -0.5^\beta| \leq |0.5|^\beta$$

but the LHS you will see equals to $0.5^\beta$. Then for any $\alpha >\beta$ you'll see that $0.5^\beta > 0.5^\alpha$, so it can't be $\alpha$ - Holder for $\beta < \alpha < 1$

Using the value of $0$ is ok because $x^\beta$ us also $\beta$ - continuous on $[0,1]$...

If you don't like that to see the argument still holds instead of $0$ use a small $\epsilon$ in it's place. Then if $f(x)$ is $\alpha$ - Holder then we would have

$$ |\epsilon^\beta - 0.5^\beta| \leq |\epsilon - 0.5|^\alpha.$$

Take the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ then you have a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

If $\alpha>\beta$, then
$$\sup_{0<x<y<1}\frac{|y^\beta-x^\beta|}{|y-x|^\alpha}\ge \sup_{0<x<1}\frac{|(2x)^\beta-x^\beta|}{|2x-x|^\alpha}=(2^\beta-1)\sup_{0<x<1}x^{\beta-\alpha}=+\infty.$$

Comment: It seems to work, thanks.

Comment: @user: You are welcome. Just a reminding: $f$ is $\alpha$-Hölder if there exists $C>0$, such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le C|x-y|^\alpha$ for any $x$ and $y$. Therefore, to show $f$ is not $\alpha$-Hölder, you have to show that such $C$ does not exist, as what I did in my answer.